# Seed amount per plant spot

Tags: seeds, planting, seedlings, lettuce

im new to gardening! 
I planted various lettuce plants but now im not sure did i did it right. I am not sure should i plant one or couple seeds per plant spot.
I checked various youtube vids and i saw people doing it both ways for the lettuce.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Scavs, could you be a little more specific about what you are asking? What did you see on that video? What are the both ways your talking about? Any picture you could add to illustrate your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no right answer.  It is up to you:

- How many pots, seed topsoil and space do you have
- How expensive are the seeds (some varieties are very expensive)
- How do you feel eradicating double seedling (but healthy)

I tend to be more in the: "*one seed, one pot*", but commercial farms tend to consider seed cheap, but labour most costly, so they tend to put more seed per pot.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer +1. Im trying to build prototype hydroponics for family. I have small plastic cups with soil in which i put the seeds in,  im waiting to get the first leafs only then ill put them in the system. Im thinking is one seed per cup maximum or i could plant about 3 seeds per cup to increase volume.

Comment: And the ever popular: •What's the germination rate  I *usually* over-plant, then thin back once they're past the cotyledon/damping off stage. https://www.planetnatural.com/pest-problem-solver/plant-disease/damping-off/